# IBM Cloud with Cloud Foundry: Error pushing nodejs app (Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase)

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, push, cloud-foundry

I am making an app with Node.js and trying to upload it to Cloud Foundry on IBM Cloud. It runs well locally but when I try tu push it shows this:

[image: cmd capture]

I share you my package.json because I think that there is the problem and my files structure. Thank you!

```
{
  "name": "pruebanode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
        "start": "node server.js"

  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@cloudant/cloudant": "^4.3.1",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "trello-kb": "^1.5.0"
  }
}
```

[image: files structure]

Comment: What Node version do you have locally and which one is in the selected buildpack?

Comment: I don`t know how, but I solved it, I tried pushing the app without interface I think the parameter is -o. Thank you.